# Lightning Out Content Security Policy

Tags: lightning-out, content-security-policy

I'm trying to use Lightning Out. It's running from within an iFrame, but I'm getting this error.

> Refused to load the script 'https://XXX.my.salesforce.com/lightning/lightning.out.js' because it violates the following Content Security Policy directive: "script-src XXX 'self'".

Is there any way around this error?

Comment: are you following all this ? https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.lightning.meta/lightning/lightning_out_requirements.htm.. esp..The origin server must be added to the Cross-Origin Resource Sharing (CORS) whitelist.

Comment: @admistCloud, this was a long time ago, so I don't remember exactly - but we ended up getting Salesforce involved and they said that it wasn't possible (I don't remember for what reason) and that we needed to re-build it in that app.